# Why am I having issues working with large group multiplication tables?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, crash, group-theory

My mathematica running on Wolfram Cloud seems to break down if I use a SymmetricGroup greater than 6. As a basic example, when I run,

```
group1 = GroupMultiplicationTable[SymmetricGroup[6]];
Print[Length[group1]];
```

I get 720 as output. However, Running the same code with 7 as in,

```
group1 = GroupMultiplicationTable[SymmetricGroup[7]];
Print[Length[group1]];
```

causes the notebook to display the running icon for about a minute, and then stop with no output. I am running this code in a notebook on Wolfram Cloud. I have tried running it on desktop Mathematica, but this also ceases to work for SymmetricGroups greater than 7.

Comment: Perhaps you are exceeding some memory limitation? Displaying the result and the `MaxMemoryUsed` for 5 and then for 6 shows how rapidly this is growing and consuming memory. From that could you estimate the size for 7,8,9,10..? It doesn't look like it is a small simple smoothly increasing amount

Comment: Hm. This would be an integer matrix of size $7! \times 7! = 5040 \times 5040$, right? That fits comfortably into memory...

Comment: Perhaps to add clarity, my end goal was to display a histogram of the orders of elements in the Symmetric Group. I have code that works when plugging in SymmetricGroups up to size 6, but using SymmetricGroup[7] fails because for some reason getting the length of the GroupMultiplicationTable returns 1 once it is 7 or greater. Furthermore, I only need to go up to SymmetricGroup[9].

Comment: You can get the histogram of orders with something like Histogram[PermutationOrder /@ GroupElements[SymmetricGroup[9]]].

Comment: You're probably exceeding the time limit, which for basic wolframcloud seems to be about one minute. See `CloudAccountData[]`, `"SessionEvaluationTimeLimit" -> Quantity[60, "Seconds"]`

Comment: Works for me on my laptop Mma in about 45s (Mac M1 Max).

Comment: I should add that I normally get an error message (`Cloud::timelimit`) when the time limit runs out, but I do not in this case. I figure that's just a buglet (or a bug, since the system seems to crash), since the time it takes for the computation to quit is about the same as the time limit.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think is happening.  There's a bug/buglet in time-constraining the call to whatever library function computes the group multiplication table.  Even on my laptop, this runs for about a minute, not the requested time constraint of 10 sec. (buglet), and then returns `$Aborted`:

```
TimeConstrained[
 GroupMultiplicationTable[SymmetricGroup[7]] // ByteCount,
 10]
```

On wolframcloud, it runs for a minute and the kernel crashes (bug).

I would think that wolframcloud would implement the `"SessionEvaluationTimeLimit"` of 60 sec. by wrapping commands in `TimeConstrained[]`. It wouldn't be hard to do it in other ways, I suppose, but `TimeConstrained[]` is already part of the WL system.  Clearly(?) there is some other stuff involved in communicating between the web-notebook and the server kernel that is probably involved, but I don't know what it is.

My advice is to report it to WRI so that they can investigate.